# kendo chart need to separate the category series from the value series

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I need to setup my line chart with category values that are daily even though there might be multiple values for each day. I still need the graph to show each data value separately.  For example, if I have five values in one day I need those five points to appear on the graph in time-order between two category axis lines.  I do not want a separate category axis line for each value point.  The best example I can give is with blood pressure readings.  Someone may test their blood pressure five times in one day.  I want those five points to appear in their relative time-order between two categories that represent today and tomorrow rather than have five different categories, one for each value point.

Is this possible?  I cannot see how through the documentation, blogs, and stackoverflow question.

Comment: I think the bottom line here is I want to build kendo line graphs that can draw data points that do not line up with the category series exactly.

Comment: If you posted the code that you have so far, it would be easier to help. I'm thinking possibly setting MajorUnits to Dates and hiding the labels for MinorUnits which would be hours?